# Bootstrap How to put 2 divs inside a li?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day everyone,

I'm designing a web with bootstrap, everything is done, one last thing that i couldn't correct is put 2 divs floating each one to the left inside a li. In desktop version works like a charm but when i resize it to be responsive it goes crazy:

[image: Desktop Version]

[image: Responsive version]

[image: Responsive small]

As you can see everything gets revolved, this is the code i'm using:

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12 hs_left hs_top_fifty">
    <h1 class="lined"> Ranking de usuarios </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="span4 hs_ranking">
    <div class="span10 hs_top_fifty hs_rank_tit hs_separador_rank">
      <h2>Top último mes</h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="span12 hs_separador_rank">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Usuario</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">Puntos</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Douglas Roos</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">25</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Javier Jimenez</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">24</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Jorge Martinez</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">23</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Manuel Briceño</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">22</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Kevin Roos</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">21</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li><div class="span6 hs_ver_mas offset3"> <a href="javascript:Ranking("mes");" class="hs_mas_btn"> Ver más </a> </div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="span4 hs_ranking">
    <div class="span10 hs_top_fifty hs_rank_tit hs_separador_rank">
      <h2>Top General</h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="span12 hs_separador_rank">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Usuario</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">Puntos</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Douglas Roos</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">25</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Javier Jimenez</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">24</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Jorge Martinez</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">23</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Manuel Briceño</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">22</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Kevin Roos</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">21</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li><div class="span6 hs_ver_mas offset3"> <a href="javascript:Ranking("general");" class="hs_mas_btn"> Ver más </a> </div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="span4 hs_ranking">
    <div class="span10 hs_top_fifty hs_rank_tit hs_separador_rank">
      <h2>Usuarios + activos</h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="span12 hs_separador_rank">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Usuario</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">Puntos</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Douglas Roos</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">25</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Javier Jimenez</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">24</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Jorge Martinez</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">23</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Manuel Briceño</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">22</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="span6 hs_nom_rank">Kevin Roos</div>
          <div class="span6 hs_ptos_rank">21</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li><div class="span6 hs_ver_mas offset3"> <a href="javascript:Ranking("activos");" class="hs_mas_btn"> Ver más </a> </div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
    .hs_ranking {
        background: url(../images/post_bg.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        min-height: 400px!important;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 0px !important;
    }
    .hs_top_fifty {
    margin-top: 50px
}
    .hs_ranking ul{
        margin:40px;
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:15px;
    }
    .hs_nom_rank{
        text-align:left;
    }
    .hs_ptos_rank{
        text-align:right;
    }
    .hs_rank_tit{
        margin-left:25px !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .hs_separador_rank{
        background: url(../images/seprator.png) repeat-x;
        background-position: bottom;
        background-size: 100% 20%;
    }
    .hs_ver_mas {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .hs_mas_btn {
        background: url(../images/mas_btn.png) no-repeat;
        height: 57px;
        padding-top: 14px;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-size: 96%
    }
    .hs_mas_btn:hover {
        background: url(../images/more_hover.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 96%;
        height: 57px;
        color: #000
    }
```

The span6 span12 and row-fluid code is the default from bootstrap,

Comment: Perhaps your image is breaking the layout `.hs-ranking` that `post_bg.png` is it fluid or.. ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i tried deleting the image from .hs-ranking but it didn't work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i gotted,

I had to change the CSS to this:

```
.hs_ranking {
    background: url(../images/post_bg.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-height: 400px!important;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.hs_ranking ul{
    margin:40px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:15px;
}
.hs_ranking ul li{
    height:16px;
}
.hs_ranking ul li:nth-child(2) .span2{
    font-size:20px;
}
.hs_ranking ul li:nth-child(3) .span2{
    font-size:16px;
}
.hs_ranking ul li:nth-child(4) .span2{
    font-size:12px;
}
.hs_ranking ul li .span12 .span6{
    width:48.93617021276595% !important;
    float:left !important;
}
.hs_ranking ul li .span12 .span2{
    width: 14.893617021276595% !important;
    float:left !important;
}
.hs_ranking ul li .span12 .span4{
    width: 31.914893617021278% !important;
    float:left !important;
}
.hs_ranking ul li .span6{
    width:48.93617021276595% !important;
}
.hs_nom_rank{
    text-align:left;
}
.hs_ptos_rank{
    text-align:right;
}
.hs_rank_tit{
    margin-left:25px !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80% !important;
}
.hs_separador_rank{
    background: url(../images/seprator.png) repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: 100% 20%;
}
.hs_ver_mas {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

And the magic occurs!